# Eclipse project contains a warning mark ... why?

Tags: java, eclipse

The following red x suggests something is wrong.

[image]

Meanwhile

- Project contains no errors and compiles fine
- Project contains no path conflicts
- Project includes all files it needs to know about
- All tests pass when ran
- Code works when executed

What would cause the red x and how can i remove it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try looking in the problems view for a detailed breakdown of build problems and warnings:

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcprbview.htm

There could be a whole range of problems related to your project without being specific to your source code.  You might not have an expected jar on your build path - for example.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a problem with the project itself. For example, you have a library defined in your build path and the library doesn't actually exist on disk.

Try right-click on project > Build Path > Configure build path > Libraries and look for problems there.

If you are not actually using any classes from the missing library, your project would still build, which would explain what you're seeing.

Comment: +1 Also, sometimes I find that closing and opening Eclipse can fix these problems - Eclipse gets a little weird if it's been open for a while.